# How to handle exceptions for multiple URLs

Tags: ruby, exception

To get favicon binary I wrote like this.

```
  def favicon_url_from_link
     # get a url from link tag
    URI('http://example.com/common/favicon.png')
  end

  def favicon_url_from_path
    URI('http://example.com/favicon.ico')
  end

  def favicon_binary_from_link
    favicon_url_from_link&.read
  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
    nil
  end

  def favicon_binary_from_path
    favicon_url_from_path&.read
  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
    nil
  end

  def favicon_binary
    favicon_binary_from_link || favicon_binary_from_path
  end
```

But I think it's a bit redundant to write `rescue` clause for each url.
How can I write it more succinct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to extract the portion that raises exceptions into a separate method, like `read_url`:

```
def favicon_binary_from_link
  read_url(favicon_url_from_link)
end

def favicon_binary_from_path
  read_url(favicon_url_from_path)
end

def read_url(url)
  url&.read
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
  nil
end

def favicon_binary
  favicon_binary_from_link || favicon_binary_from_path
end
```